# Windows Builder Eclipse Error -1

Tags: windows, eclipse

I installed Windows Builder on Eclipse but when I try to create a new Project Palette I receive the error: 
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
-1

Do you know how can I work with Windows Builder over Eclipse?

Thanks a lot

Comment: And what does the error log says?

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

I uninstalled the WindowBuilder. And then reinstalled it from a different web source.

You have to be careful that the version that you are installing is the appropriate version for your IDE.

For Example I have Eclipse Kepler and for this reason I installed my WindowBuilder from:
WindowBuilder Pro Update Site - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/4.3

If you are working with Eclipse Juno you have to install WindowBuilder from:
WindowBuilder Pro Update Site - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/4.2

I hope it helps.
Fab.